# Avoid repeating parts of a jquery script

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check some input-fields before submiting a form. But this code looks a little complicated for me. As there are some parts which are repeated, I think it should be possible to optimize/shrink the code.

What is be done by the code:

1. Check the input fields of a table
2. If there is an error, a class is been added
3. If there is an error-class -> the form will not be submited

**JS:**

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    $("tr").each(function() {
        $.each($(this).children("td:eq(1)"),function() {
            var str = $(this).children('input').val().replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".");
            $(this).children('input').val(str);
            if (str.match(/^\d+(-?\d+|\d*)$/)) {
                $(this).children('input').removeClass('error');
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('input').addClass('error');
            }
        });
        $.each($(this).children("td:eq(2)"),function() {
            var str = $(this).children('input').val().replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".");
            $(this).children('input').val(str);
            if (str.match(/^\d+(\.\d+|\d*)(-?\d+(\.\d+|\d*)|\d*)$/)) {
                $(this).children('input').removeClass('error');
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('input').addClass('error');
            }
        });
        $.each($(this).children("td:eq(3)"),function() {
            var str = $(this).children('input').val();
            if (str.match(/^[a-zA-Zµ]+$/i)) {
                $(this).children('input').removeClass('error');
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('input').addClass('error');
            }
        });
    });
    if (!$('.error').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I tried to put some parts in a seperate function, but I didn't get it :-(
I think a separate function would be better i.e. if I want to check two different input fields for the same case...

Comment: One thing you can do to shorten that (but not an answer to the question) is `$(this).children('input').toggleClass('error', /^[a-zA-Zµ]+$/i.test(str));` instead of the `if (match) { remove } else { add }`.

Comment: Also, `something.each(function() { });` is the usual way to loop through a jQuery set, rather than `$.each(something, function() { });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a lot of code you could make a function that makes the checks:

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        validateTD(self, 1, /^\d+(-?\d+|\d*)$/, true);
        validateTD(self, 2, /^\d+(\.\d+|\d*)(-?\d+(\.\d+|\d*)|\d*)$/, true);
        validateTD(self, 3, /^[a-zA-Zµ]+$/i);
    });
    if (!$('.error').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

function validateTD(tr, number, pattern, removeSpacesAndReplaceCommasWithDot) {

    if(removeSpacesAndReplaceCommasWithDot == undefined) {

        removeSpacesAndReplaceCommasWithDot = false;

    }

    $.each(tr.children("td:eq(" + number + ")"),function() {
        if(removeSpacesAndReplaceCommasWithDot) {
            var str = $(this).children('input').val().replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".");
            $(this).children('input').val(str);
        }
        else {
            var str = $(this).children('input').val();
        }
        if (str.match(pattern)) {
            $(this).children('input').removeClass('error');
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('input').addClass('error');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right! Try my updated answer @ user3142695.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, just making it clear! And you were right again, totally missed that row, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make yourself an array of rules, extract the bits that change (selector, value prep, and regex test), then loop through the rules:

```
var rules = [
    {
        selector: "td:eq(1)",
        prepValue: function(val) { return val.replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,"."); },
        regex:    /^\d+(-?\d+|\d*)$/
    },
    {
        selector: "td:eq(2)",
        prepValue: function(val) { return val.replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,"."); },
        regex:    /^\d+(\.\d+|\d*)(-?\d+(\.\d+|\d*)|\d*)$/
    },
    {
        selector: "td:eq(2)",
        prepValue: function(val) { return val; },
        regex:    /^[a-zA-Zµ]+$/i
    }
];
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.each(rules, function(i, rule) {
            $.each($this.children(rule.selector),function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    input = $this.children('input'),
                    str = rule.prepValue(input.val());
                input.val(str);
                input.toggleClass('error', rule.regex.test(str));
            });
        });
    });
    if (!$('.error').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is this working?

I put a map and put different data in it
then you can reduce some code.

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    var map = {};
    map["1"] = /^\d+(-?\d+|\d*)$/;
    map["2"] = /^\d+(\.\d+|\d*)(-?\d+(\.\d+|\d*)|\d*)$/;
    map["3"] = /^[a-zA-Zµ]+$/i;
    $("tr").each(function() {
        for(var key in map){
            $.each($(this).children("td:eq(" + key + ")"),function() {
                var str = $(this).children('input').val().replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".");
                $(this).children('input').val(str);
                if (str.match(map[key])) {
                    $(this).children('input').removeClass('error');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).children('input').addClass('error');
                }
            });

        }
    });
    if (!$('.error').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: oh I made a mistake, I would like to use Object instead of Array, which I can put key name which decided by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i belive is to put some of the logic in the html. Basically when you are constructing the hmtl put the attribute  data-pattern="YourRegex" and the class="has-pattern" into your inputs.

Afterwards you can do this:

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    $('.has-patter').each(function() {
      var str = $(this).val().replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".");
      var re = new RegExp($(this).attr('data-pattern'), "gi");
      $(this).toggleClass('error', re.test(str));
    }
// if there are errors  prevent Default and stop submit

});
```

Not to mention there is actually an htmnl5 attribute called pattern, which does the same, but without you needing to write any javascript. It is not supported in Safari tho.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the regular expressions in an array and determining the index of each `td` element can save you the repetition and using `.toggleClass` can save you a few lines of code.

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    var re = [
        /^\d+(-?\d+|\d*)$/,
        /^\d+(\.\d+|\d*)(-?\d+(\.\d+|\d*)|\d*)$/,
        /^[a-zA-Zµ]+$/i
    ];        
    $("tr").each(function() {
        $.each($(this).children("td:gt(0)"),function() {
            var index = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:gt(0)').index( this ),
                str = $(this).children('input').val().replace(/ /g,"").replace(/,/g,".");
            $(this).children('input').val(str);
            $(this).children('input').toggleClass( 'error', !str.match( re[index] ) );
        });
    });
    if (!$('.error').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```